# WebRTC - Chrome mDNS creates invalid host candidates in local sdp. Is there a way to exclude host candidates from generating?

Tags: webrtc, sdp, mdns, rtcpeerconnection

Chrome's mDNS implementation creates invalid host candidates in local sdp.  We have STUN and TURN servers, which generates srflx and relay candidates. But because of invalid host address, stun is failing altogether and this is explained better [in this blog](https://bloggeek.me/psa-mdns-and-local-ice-candidates-are-coming/) .  Is there a way to exclude host candidates from generating?

Comment: you can still remove them from the sdp before signaling it?

Comment: @PhilippHancke we filtered at the server end

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, too. In WebRTC, mDNS create an obfuscated host address and it also blocks srflx address if the computer connected to public IP directly without a router. And host address obfuscating is now done not only by Chrome but also by Firefox, Safari, etc...

I found that the host candidate can be blocked [in Firefox, by setting "true" the "media.peerconnection.ice.no_host" property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiGzL.png). But, I couldn't find how I can block host candidate in Chrome.